# i am not able to call the method using apache camel quartz2

Tags: java, apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

i need to invoke the method base on the cron pattern. this is my java code .where i included one method and this method i need to call.i try in google but not getting any idea how to call.

```
public class Schedule {
int i;
public  String  show()
{ 
    return "hi"+i++;

}

public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
{   
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {
            from("quartz2://myGroup/myfirstrigger?cron=0/2+*+*+*+*+?").to(new      Schedule().show());

        }
    });
    context.start();    
}

 }
```

i am not sure also this is right or not

Comment: i am using apache camel

Comment: The code snippet that you have provided doesn't show that you have started the camel context. Call the start method on camel context for this to work. But I find this weird to have started the camel context in a JSP page and a route that calls a method in it.Could you explain your complete use case ?

Comment: Also posted on Camel user mailing list where the answer is explained - http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/how-to-call-java-method-using-quartz2-tp5742192.html

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the documentation on bean binding ([Here](http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html)). I think your route would be better like the following:

```
from("quartz2://myGroup/myfirstrigger?cron=0/2+*+*+*+*+?")
  .bean(Schedule.class, "show");
```

Comment: after modified my code like above then i am getting exception like.
here url  http://www.docdroid.net/5jhl/amguity.txt.html

Comment: This is an ambiguity on the chosen method. Read the documentation about this here: http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html